# Value of $\sum^{99}_{n=1}g(1+(2n-1)\pi)$, where $g$ is the inverse of $f(x)=2x+\cos x+\sin^2 x$

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions such that $g(f(x))=x$ and $f(x)=2x+\cos x+\sin^2 x$. Then $\displaystyle \sum^{99}_{n=1}g\bigg(1+(2n-1)\pi\bigg)$ is equal to …?

Solution I try:

$$g(1+\pi)+g(1+3\pi)+\cdots \cdots +g(1+97\pi).$$

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverses of each other, then

$$f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x.$$

From $g(f(x))=x\implies g(2x+\cos x+\sin^2 x)= x$.

How do I find series sum, help me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $g(2x+\cos x + {\sin}^2 x) = x$?

Comment: Notice that $f(\pi/2) = \pi + 1$.  This should help you because $g(f(\pi/2)) = \pi/2$.

Comment: The expression "$\sum^{99}_{n=1}g(1+\pi)+g(1+3\pi)+\cdots \cdots +g(1+97\pi)$" doesn't make sense. If you've already expanded the summation, why is the sigma symbol still there? And besides, either you've made a typo in the last term or you've only expanded up to $n=49$ instead of $n=99$.

Comment: Follow D.B., find $f((n-1/2)\pi)$ first.

Comment: @DB explain me plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$$
and
$$f(\frac{n\pi}2)=1+n\pi$$
thus
$$g(1+n\pi)=f^{-1}(1+n\pi)=\frac{n\pi}2$$
for all odd $n$.

By the way, $$\sum_{n=1}^kn=\frac{k(k+1)}2$$